# QGIS composer exports corrupted images

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

I'm using QGIS 2.18.9 on Windows 10. I've created an atlas in composer and when exporting images, the first few will export fine and then the map image becomes corrupt or fills as completely blank. Here is an example of a corrupted image (colored right-side of main map)

[image]

I'm using the OpenLayers Statmen plugin for the basemap. I've tried a few others and they either fail as well or do not allow the map tile to be printed at the scale. If it clear cache and reboot it will work for about 7-10 images and then fail again.

Comment: have you tried the QuickMapServices plugin instead of OpenLayers plugin? I used to find with OpenLayers plugin it helped to wait for a few minutes to let the tiles download before attempting to save the image, the corruption you see may be because those tiles weren't fully loaded. (That was for a single map though, never tried OpenLayers plugin with an atlas)